# How to convert HDD from GPT partitioned to partitionless keeping BTRFS filesystem intact?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, filesystem, gpt, btrfs

I have a 8TB Seagate Archive HDD partitioned with GPT: BTRFS filesystem (1TB approx), all the rest is now free. I would like to convert this HDD to partitionless (let BTRFS manage full drive) while keeping BTRFS filesystem data intact. Is it possible at all?

Ubuntu Server 14.04 (Btrfs v3.12, Linux version 3.19.0-64-generic)

NOTE: it is non-boot disk, storage only

Comment: I do not think it is possible. Why not extend the btrfs to the whole disk instead? Having GPT is more convenient in most cases.

Comment: Thats what I just did because there is no solution so far, indeed

Comment: In theory, you could do it with `dd`, by copying everything back by whatever the current gap is between the start of the partition and the start of the disk. This would be extremely risky, though. It's very unlikely that going to a setup without a partition table would add any real benefits; at most, you'll recover about 1 MiB of space, which is trivial on an 8 TB disk. It's likely to be better to use GParted to expand the current partition or create another one in the free space.

Answer (score -1):

I have no experience with Btrfs (more experience with ZFS) but for attention to *partitions*, the first utility that comes to mind is gdisk(8).

[GPT fdisk text-mode partitioning tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gdisk/)

An outline:

```
$ sudo gdisk
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Type device filename, or press <Enter> to exit: /dev/sda
Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 51A560B1-D116-479F-A8A2-2A8F86C89931
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953525134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 3437 sectors (1.7 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         1050623   512.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   2         1050624         2050047   488.0 MiB   8300  
   3         2050048      1953523711   930.5 GiB   8300  

Command (? for help): r

Recovery/transformation command (? for help): ?
b       use backup GPT header (rebuilding main)
c       load backup partition table from disk (rebuilding main)
d       use main GPT header (rebuilding backup)
e       load main partition table from disk (rebuilding backup)
f       load MBR and build fresh GPT from it
g       convert GPT into MBR and exit
h       make hybrid MBR
i       show detailed information on a partition
l       load partition data from a backup file
m       return to main menu
o       print protective MBR data
p       print the partition table
q       quit without saving changes
t       transform BSD disklabel partition
v       verify disk
w       write table to disk and exit
x       extra functionality (experts only)
?       print this menu

Recovery/transformation command (? for help): m

Command (? for help): x

Expert command (? for help): ?
a       set attributes
c       change partition GUID
d       display the sector alignment value
e       relocate backup data structures to the end of the disk
g       change disk GUID
h       recompute CHS values in protective/hybrid MBR
i       show detailed information on a partition
l       set the sector alignment value
m       return to main menu
n       create a new protective MBR
o       print protective MBR data
p       print the partition table
q       quit without saving changes
r       recovery and transformation options (experts only)
s       resize partition table
t       transpose two partition table entries
u       replicate partition table on new device
v       verify disk
w       write table to disk and exit
z       zap (destroy) GPT data structures and exit
?       print this menu

Expert command (? for help): q
$ uname -a
Linux momh167-gjp4-kubuntu-hpelitebook850g2 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$
```

(Could **zap (destroy) GPT data structures and exit** form part of a solution?)

Comment: According to man gdisk, MBR structures are still remain in place, so drive is not converted to partition-less...